# Word randomly creating file called English

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2010

2nd Revision since I'm getting new information on this problem.

Word is randomly creating a file called English in places that a Word document has been opened or Saved to.  This includes network drives and local drives.  One person says that the English file is created when word crashes when trying to open, the other when they open a Word Document, and another when they save a Word file.  Each person is only aware of one of the scenarios creating the file.  It seems so random that I can't seem to figure out a clear "what could be causing this issue".  Only seems to happen with Microsoft Word which is the only common thing I can find.

Contents of one of the English files, it looks like some kind of log file.  I tried seeking help from a few of the developers here, but they are unsure what to make of the file.

20.07.12 08:43:41
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 54
20.07.12 08:43:41
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 58
20.07.12 08:43:41
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 62
20.07.12 08:43:42
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 66
20.07.12 08:43:42
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 70
20.07.12 08:43:42
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 75
20.07.12 08:43:42
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 79
20.07.12 08:43:42
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 83
20.07.12 08:43:42
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 91
20.07.12 08:43:42
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 99
20.07.12 08:43:42
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 103
20.07.12 08:43:42
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 106
20.07.12 08:43:42
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 112
20.07.12 08:43:42
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 119
14.08.12 08:08:45
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 54
14.08.12 08:08:45
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 58
14.08.12 08:08:45
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 62
14.08.12 08:08:46
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 66
14.08.12 08:08:46
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 70
14.08.12 08:08:46
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 75
14.08.12 08:08:46
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 79
14.08.12 08:08:46
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 83
14.08.12 08:08:46
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 91
14.08.12 08:08:46
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 99
14.08.12 08:08:46
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 103
14.08.12 08:08:46
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 106
14.08.12 08:08:46
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 112
14.08.12 08:08:46
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 119
20.08.12 09:57:52
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 54
20.08.12 09:57:52
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 58
20.08.12 09:57:52
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 62
20.08.12 09:57:53
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 66
20.08.12 09:57:53
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 70
20.08.12 09:57:53
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 75
20.08.12 09:57:53
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 79
20.08.12 09:57:53
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 83
20.08.12 09:57:53
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 91
20.08.12 09:57:53
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 99
20.08.12 09:57:53
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 103
20.08.12 09:57:53
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 106
20.08.12 09:57:53
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 112
20.08.12 09:57:53
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 119
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 54
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 58
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 62
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 66
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 70
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 75
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 79
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 83
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 91
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 99
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 103
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 106
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 112
04.09.12 08:46:34
passed .\HttpFunctions.cpp, 119

Comment: What happens when it crashes? What is the exact syntax of the error message you receive when it crashes? Is it when saving a document? If so, are you saving the document locally or to a networked device? If to a network, with what protocol?

Comment: Yeah. Do you get any error messages, or does it just go down immediately?

Comment: So i was misinformed that everyone could create it.  Once the person is back at there desk I will have them run through it again to see what errors they recieve, if i recall correctly it just says that it has crashed and needs to close.  Will post further details once i have them.